# Disqus commenting system with Gujarati and Hindi Language support

Tags: locale, disqus

I am creating a [blog](http://baseonthoughts.com) with base language as **Gujarati**.
I am also adding language support for **English** and **Hindi**. I know how to do that from development aspect.
But I got confused when I realised that I also need to change Locale (or something like this) for disqus commenting system.

**Can anyone suggest me whether I can add indian language support to [Disqus Commenting System](http://www.disqus.com/) or not?**

Answer (score 0):

Languages in Disqus are added automatically when fully translated *and* reviewed. At the time of writing this, Hindi is 34% translated, which is below the threshold.

You can see the status for each language here:

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/disqus/resource/js/

You can also volunteer to translate on that page, which is always much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

'languages' in Disqus are included instantly when completely converted and analyzed. At the time of composing this, Hindi is 34% converted, which is below the limit.

[NyLotto](http://nylottov.com/)